# Как присовить переменной длину другой переменной

Tags: bash, shell

У меня есть скрипт. В нем есть часть

```
$string | wc -c
```

которая считает длину строки $string. Мне нужно это длину записать в переменную.

```
result=$string | wc -c
```

не работает. Пытался ставить `$(..)` , `` `..` ``, `{..}` и все их возможные комбинации, но все не работает. `echo $result` выводит 0. Как это работает?

Comment: в обратные апострофы команду заключите

Comment: Да я пытался написать, что я это пробовал (серое двоеточие). `result=0;
result=\`$path | wc -c\`;
echo $result`
выводит 0. 
При то, что 
`echo $path | wc -c;`
выводит 13

Comment: А почему вы в аопстрофы заключаете $path без echo, она нужна что бы подать на вход wc значение ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, так:

```
$ S="asdf"
$ X=$(wc -c <<< $S)
$ echo $X
```

Comment: Безмерно благодарю!!

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
result=$(echo $string | wc -c)
```

Answer (score 0):

А если вот так?

```
A="string"
B=${#A}
```